# Saving iteration results in a CSV sheet

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop with 100 iterations for an analysis. I got a result in each iteration and stored the subset of results in a b[[i]] list format. Now, I want to save all b[[1]], b[[2]],...,b[[100]] in a sheet, but I want to know what is the result for each iteration (for example there is a space between them, like below table) . The number of results rows is different, but the columns are fixed. Some of the results are empty, so when I use "write.list", I get the below errors. Is there any solution?

Table: first 2 rows are for b[[1]], then a space and the fourth row is b[[2]], and so on.

| name | size | pvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a.1 | 5 | 0.01 |
| b.1 | 2 | 0.005 |
|  |  |  |
| c.2 | 2 | 0.005 |

Codes:

```
b=list()
for(i in 1:100)
    {
        
        # Run analysis
        
        Result=SAMGS(GS=GS,DATA=ndata,cl=ncl,nbPermutations=1000) 
        
    
        r=data.frame()
        r=subset(Result, pvalue < 0.1)   
        b[[i]]=r
    
     }
write.list(b,file="Res.csv", row.names =TRUE)
```

Error:

> Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Comment: irritation? did you mean iteration?

Comment: Yes! Sorry! I hope I can edit my question.

Comment: Perhaps instead of writing the list, try loading the list of dataframes into a single dataframe and write that to file, e.g. `results <- bind_rows(b, .id = "Iteration"); write.csv(results, "res.csv", row.names = TRUE)`. If it 'fails' at the bind_rows stage you may get a more informative error message.